# How are CheY, CheA, CheW, CheZ pronounced in speech?

Tags: molecular-biology, terminology

This is a quick followup question to [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39657/abbreviations-for-molecules-what-are-chew-chea-chey/39662#39662) about proteins that play important roles in chemotaxis:

How does one pronounce the protein names "CheY", "CheW", etc., in English?  My guess would be that they're pronounced like "key why", "key double-u", etc.

(I want to refer to these proteins in a philosophy of science presentation, but don't have much background in molecular biology. I know about chemotaxis only from reading.)

Comment: That's certainly how I would pronounce them: you're abbreviating 'chemotaxis', so "key-Y' makes sense. You could probably get away with 'C-H-E-Y' or 'Chemotaxis-Y' but I'd use the first one. When they're unpronounceable spell it, otherwise say it if you can. There aren't official guidelines on gene symbol pronunciation, so you're on your own.

Comment: These are not English words that have any defined pronunciation. These are more like code-words. You can pronounce them as you want. For these proteins, I just pronounce them as if they were abbreviations and not acronyms.

Comment: @Resonating, WYSYWIG, these are answers, and the best answers possible, I suspect.  Each of your comments helped me.  You should post them as answers, so that I can upvote them.

Comment: Resonating, @WYSYWIG, these are answers, and the best answers possible, I suspect. Each of your comments helped me. You should post them as answers, so that I can upvote them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, these are not real words and there is no authority on their pronunciation. Given that [Che is an abbreviation of chemotaxis](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39657/abbreviations-for-molecules-what-are-chew-chea-chey), I would pronounce it the same as key.